# I am using composer to autoload the file but when i run my code he is not able to find the class

Tags: php

When I run this I got error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ashwini123\queyHelper' not found in /home/ashwinibhandare/dev/training/ComposerBasics/src/queryHelper/ViewCustomerData.php:4
>
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/ashwinibhandare/dev/training/ComposerBasics/public/index.php(4): include()
>
> ## 1 {main}
>
> ```
>   thrown in /home/ashwinibhandare/dev/training/ComposerBasics/src/queryHelper/ViewCustomerData.php on line 4
> ```

In my project there are two folders public and src .in public folder there is index.php file and in src contains one more folder queryHelper which contains database connection file, viewCustomerdata.php file and queryhelper.php file. I have added the namespace to DbConnection.php file. Why do I get this error? As I am using namespace correctly?

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "ashwinibhandare/composer-basics",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Ashwini Bhandare",
            "email": "a.bhandare@easternenterprise.com"
        }
    ],

     "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"ashwini123\\": "src/queryHelper"}
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

include '../src/queryHelper/ViewCustomerData.php';
?>
ViewCustomerData.php
<?php
use ashwini123\queyHelper;

$Crude=new queyHelper();
$sql="select * from users";
$selectData=$Crude->getData($sql);

?>
```

queryHelper.php

```
<?php
use ashwini123\DbConnection;
class queyHelper extends DbConnection {

    public function __construct()
    {

         parent::__construct();

    }

    public function getData($query)
    {
      try {

            $sql=$this->connection->prepare($query);
            $sql->execute();
            $count = $sql->rowCount();

            if($count)
            {
                $selectData =  $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }  

            return $selectData;
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) {
           die("Failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

DbConnection.php

```
<?php
namespace ashwini123;
class DbConnection {


    public $connection;

    public function __construct()
    { 
        if (!isset($this->connection)) {

            try {
                    $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crudOperation",'root', 'root');
                    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    return $this->connection;


                } 
                catch(PDOException $e) {

                    die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $e->getMessage());

                }

                } else {
                            echo "Connection failed";
                        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try composer dump-autoload -o

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
ashwini123\queyHelper
```

should be

```
 ashwini123\queryHelper
```

Moreover modify PSR-4 mapping as follows

```
"psr-4": {"ashwini123\\": "src/"}
```

Comment: yes but my foldername is correct queryHelper and file under it is  queyHelper.php

Comment: i also did the change of class name still I got Error=PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ashwini123\queryHelper' not found in /home/ashwinibhandare/dev/training/ComposerBasics/src/queryHelper/ViewCustomerData.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ashwinibhandare/dev/training/ComposerBasics/public/index.php(4): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ashwinibhandare/dev/training/ComposerBasics/src/queryHelper/ViewCustomerData.php on line 4

Comment: @AshwiniBhandare is the whole project under `src/queryHelper`? If it is, it's correct to keep that PSR-4. Otherwise you should follow mine and modify `ashwini123\queryHelper` in `ashwini123\queryHelper\queryHelper`